# Facing Issue while configuring Firebase to my application using flutterfire cli

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-tools

I am unable to connect firebase to my flutter application using CLI.

```
i Found 0 Firebase projects.
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase projects:list --json
ERROR: Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
```

I have been stuck here for over a day, I tried to create a new project and did everything from start still none changed.

node and flutterfire are already installed.

for the record I have already tried running:

```
firebase login --reauth
```

command also tried logging out and logging in again.

I also tried running :

```
firebase projects:list
!  Authenticating with `FIREBASE_TOKEN` is deprecated and will be removed in a future major version of `firebase-tools`. Instead, use a service account key with `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
× Preparing the list of your Firebase projects

Error: Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
```

Please help

Comment: Have you checked the `firebase-debug.log` file?

Comment: I am trying to find this file but i don't know where is that located, I tried searching it on project's file but still couldn't find it.

Comment: Have you run `firebase init` and initialize firestore and it will generate the log file

Comment: it says:
[debug] [2023-12-08T15:56:06.005Z] HTTP Error: 401, Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
[debug] [2023-12-08T15:56:06.283Z] FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 401, Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
  
along with same errors.

Comment: But I have logged in correctly and idk how many times I did logged in, it also says:
!  Authenticating with `FIREBASE_TOKEN` is deprecated and will be removed in a future major version of `firebase-tools`. Instead, use a service account key with `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
× Preparing the list of your Firebase projects

Comment: after running '''firebase init''' it asically return the same error ,? Please select an option: Use an existing project

Error: Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
PS E:\StudioProjects\electralink>

Comment: Have you created firebase project in `https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/`?
Are you sure you are using the same user for loggining in the cli and firebase?

Comment: Yes I have created it, and I am using same user.